# Creating a custom slug

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey so currently when I post to WordPress (Automatically) I am using something like this

```
$content = '<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$row['vid_code'].'?vq=hd1080&modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&controls=1&iv_load_policy=3&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&autohide=0&disablekb=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';


// Create post object
$my_post = array(
     'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( trim( $row['title'] ) ),
     'post_content'  => $content,
     'post_status'   => 'publish',
     'post_author'   => 1,
     'post_category' => array( 3 ),
     'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
```

Now i am wondering what would I need to add in order for me to get the `'. $row['video'] .'` portion of my code to be my websites custom slug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question.

Try adding this into your code and it should return what you're looking for.
`$new_url = sanitize_title(''.$row['vid_code'].'');`.

So it would look like this below.

```
$content = '<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$row['vid_code'].'?vq=hd1080&modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&controls=1&iv_load_policy=3&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&autohide=0&disablekb=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';


// Create post object
$my_post = array(
     'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( trim( $row['title'] ) ),
     'post_content'  => $content,
     'post_status'   => 'publish',
     'post_author'   => 1,
     'post_category' => array( 3 ),
     'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);

$new_url = sanitize_title(''.$row['vid_code'].'');
```